# How can I modify my mongodb query so that the results do not contain specific values stored in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using `mongoose` and defined a model for a comment section in my app:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    my_username: {type: String, required: true},
    text_content: {type: String},
    hashtags: {type: [String]},
    photo_content: {type: String},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Now when I'm downloading all comments that belongs to specific timeframe and contains hashtags, I have:

```
var hashtagsInput = req.body.hashtags;
var query= {};

query.$and = [];

if(startDate != undefined && endDate != undefined) {
    var startDate = new Date(req.param('startDate'));
    var endDate = new Date(req.param('endDate'));
    query.$and.push({"created_at":{$gte: startDate}});
    query.$and.push({"created_at":{$lte: endDate}});
}

if (hashtagsInput != undefined) {
    var hashtags = hashtagsInput.split(",");
    query.$and.push({"hashtags":{$in: hashtags}});
}
```

Now I'm trying to add another case to the query - besides an array of hashtags I'm passing array of blocked users:

```
var blockedUsers = req.body.blockedUsers;
```

I want to avoid every comment that has an author equal to any of the entries in blockedUsers. so basically I want to have `not in` query. Can you give me a hint of how to construct this additional condition in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this should do the trick:

```
if (blockedUsers) {
  query.$and.push({"my_username": {$not: {$in: blockedUsers}}});
}
```

or, even better:

```
if (blockedUsers) {
  query.$and.push({"my_username": {$nin: blockedUsers}});
}
```

Or possibly you need to split it on commas like you do with hashtags - you didn't specify how you pass the blocked users:

```
var blockedUsers = req.body.blockedUsers;
if (blockedUsers) {
  var blocked = blockedUsers.split(',');
  query.$and.push({"my_username": {$nin: blocked}});
}
```

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: yes, I have to split it in a similar way to hashtags, your solution looks great, thanks!